# How to split Devise edit page form into two pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm trying to figure how to split form from Devise edit page into two pages as it has too many fields right now. So the goal is for users to be able to update their profile information from separate pages. I'm fairly new to Rails so I don't understand what's going... I haven't created new controller for this purpose, I'm using existing Devise controller... The error I'm getting is that there is no edit_profile action defined in Registrations Controller even though there is..

What I did:

Created a new view style.html.erb with a form and it's under registrations views. I just copied to form from existing edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), layout: :horizontal do |f| %>
```

Added this to routes:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
  **get "users/style" => "registrations#edit_profile", as: "edit_profile"**
```

Here is my registration controller so far:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :profile, :update, :destroy]

  protected 


  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if resource.encrypted_password.blank? # || params[:password].blank?
      resource.email = params[:email] if params[:email]
      if !params[:password].blank? && params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation]
        logger.info "Updating password"
        resource.password = params[:password]
        resource.save
      end
      if resource.valid?
        resource.update_without_password(params)
      end
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end

    def edit_profile

    end


end
```

Comment: It shouldn't be protected. Move it over `protected` keyword

Comment: I did that, now I'm getting a new error when I try to access /users/style: Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/style". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

Comment: I added devise_scope :user do get "/users/style" => "registrations#edit_profile"
 end but again there is a new error "Template is missing"

Comment: Have you considered using Javascript / CSS to split the presentation of the form up instead? There are many prebuilt solutions like [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples) that make it pretty easy. Seems a lot less complicated and will give a better user experience.

Comment: Hi @max yes I considered, but I'm also considering UI so I need forms to be on separate pages...

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution if anybody needs it:

Create a new controller that inherits from DeviseController

```
class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def style
        @user = current_user
        if @user
            render :style
        else
            render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
         end 
    end
 end
```

Step 2, create a view under registrations devise views: style.html.erb. Just copy the part of the form from edit.html.erb that you need here.

Step 3, add this to your routes:

```
devise_scope :user do 
     match 'users/style' => 'registration#style', :via => [:get], :as => 'style'
end
```

So now when I access /users/style I'm able to edit and update second part of the form.

Comment: Just a neatpick... The convention is `RegistrationsController`, not `RegistrationController`. Then in routes it would be `'registrations#style'`, not `'registration#style'`. Also, a shorter syntax would be: `get 'users/style', to: 'registrations#style', as: 'style'`